# mysql trigger compare operators

Tags: mysql, if-statement, triggers, operators

I have the code bellow:

```
DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS before_insert_test;

DELIMITER $$

CREATE TRIGGER DB1.before_insert_test
BEFORE INSERT ON DB1.t1 FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    -- condition to check
    IF (select length(NEW.m_phone) > 10) THEN
        set new.m_phone = '1111111111';
    END IF;
END$$
```

in the IF statement the comarison works with an "=" but not with either "<>", "!=" or ">".

Has anyone seen this before and can point me in the right direction?

Comment: If the lengths are equal, then the are not "not equal", "not equal" or "greater than".  The `if` matches `=`, it is not going to match the other operations.  On another subject, the `select` is superfluous.

Comment: I would recommend using the `CHAR_LENGTH()` function instead of `LENGTH()` in order to count the number of characters (rather than the number of bytes). Also, as @GordonLinoff mentioned you should not be using `SELECT` since you can access the column values for this row without it.

Comment: I've tried char_length.  I need the "not equal", and I've tried "greater than" and "=" operator.  None return an error but the "=" at least sets the value to "1111111111" while the "<>" does nothing even though the test file has:1111111111
2345678901
2345678901
4589187934
22222222222222222
1234567890
0122323234     --so clearly has values that have length > than 10.

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using? See [SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae8b2/1).

Comment: I am an idiot, I wanted to compare the file input value not the table row value.  Thanks, all.